# Vue3 app after logout throws CORS policy error

Tags: authentication, axios, cors, vuejs3

I have Vue3 app which makes requests with Axios. As I logout from the app and then login again app starts throwing error

> create:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://vue.tatrytec.eu/'
> (redirected from 'https://tatrytec.eu/api/article/store') from origin
> 'https://vue.tatrytec.eu' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

One thing I dont understand is that as I reload the page it starts working and error is gone. The code is still the same. How can reload has impact to the CORS error?

The app code for Axios is in this [Github repository](https://github.com/camohub/tatrytec-vue-admin/blob/master/src/main.js#L18).

```
import axios from "axios"
window.axios = axios;
//axios.defaults.baseURL = apiRoutes.API_URL_SHORT;
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
let authToken = localStorage.getItem('authToken');
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + authToken;
axios.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'https://vue.tatrytec.eu';
```

Hope somebody knows cause I have no idea what happened there.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was in the login form axios setting. There was this code

```
axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
};
```

I dont know where I found it but this garbage code rewrites whole common object in axios settings. So I lost all other headers. Really would like to know where I found this code. The proper style is to use array syntax like `common['Authorization'] = ...`  Vrrrrr.